# Asterisk IVR load testing using sipp

Tags: sip, asterisk, ivr

I need to do load testing of an asterisk IVR hosted on aws. I am facing problem how to use scenario files to place a call and then send an DTMF signal.

i am able to use sipp commands to generate call against an extension. but don't know how to do load testing of IVR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [play pcap capability](http://sipp.sourceforge.net/doc/reference.html#PCAP+Play). 
There's an example [uac_pcap.xml](http://sipp.sourceforge.net/doc/uac_pcap.xml.html).

Check around line 97: `<!-- Play an out of band DTMF '1'`

Now this requires that you've preferred some captures of the RTP flow you want to replay (for example including the 101 telephony-events you want to play)

Comment: Can you suggest some tutorial to which explains all this?

Comment: @SAIR, check the sipp documentation in the links I refer to. One of the builtin scenarios (the uac_pcap.xml) one seems to be similar to what you want to do.